# Can I send automatic, scheduled e-mails about expiring or just-expired memberships?

Tags: civimail, civimember, scheduled-reminders, civirules

Using CiviCRM 4.6.11, Drupal 7. We want to create a workflow for membership renewals, part of which will include automatic, scheduled e-mails to members with expiring or just-expired memberships. I can create a Smart Group based on membership expiration date, then create a (say) daily,weekly scheduled job to send an e-mail to Smart Group members.

Is this the best or only way?

I'm also checking out the [CiviRules extension](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+-+how+to+make+your+own) compatability with 4.6.11 and 4.7 then checking out using CiviRules to create such a workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple scheduled reminders are already possible out of the box using the "Scheduled Reminders" feature.

[From the online book](http://book.civicrm.org/user/email/scheduled-reminders/):

> **Creating and managing scheduled reminders**
>
> Scheduled reminders can be created from the administration page at **Administer >
> Communications > Schedule Reminders** or during the creation of an
> event.
>
> *From the administration page:*
>
> 1. Click on Add Reminder.
> 2. Give your reminder a name that will help you identify it if you need to edit it in the future.
> 3. Select an entity for your scheduled reminder. This will bring up a further set of options relevant to that entity: activities have
>    activity types and statuses; membership gives membership types and
>    statuses, and so on. These secondary options are (usually)
>    multi-select fields, so you can choose to include more than one option
>    in each field.
> 4. Choose when to send the reminder. This can be a set date or an amount of time before or after the start or end of your chosen entity.
> 5. If you want to send more than one reminder, check the Repeat box. This gives you choices about the interval of repetition and when the
>    repetition should end.
> 6. Check Record activity for automated email if you want a record of the contacts who received this reminder.
> 7. Fill in From Name and/or From Email if you don't want this reminder to come from the default name and email address for your
>    site.
> 8. Refine or add to your recipient list. For more about your choices, see Limiting or adding to your recipient list in this chapter.
> 9. Choose to send your reminder as an email, an SMS or either depending on the preferred method(s) of communications for the
>    contact.
> 10. Compose your message. You can use Message Templates or write the message from scratch. Note that you cannot save your message as a new
>     template or modify an existing template from this screen, so if you
>     are writing a reminder for the first time and you think you will want
>     to re-use it, consider creating it as a Message Template instead.
> 11. Click Save when you are are done.
>
> Reminders can be edited, disabled, or deleted from **Administer >
> Communications > Schedule Reminders**.
>
> IMPORTANT: Your system administrator will need to ensure that the
> *Send Scheduled Reminders* scheduled job is enabled and runs at least once a day. Refer to the Scheduled Jobs chapter for configuration
> details.

Comment: thanks so much, I've used Scheduled Reminders in the past for Events e-mail reminders but did not realize they also work for e-mails about membership status, to Groups or anyone.